# Search in Elasticsearch using query_string on specific ids

Tags: elasticsearch

If I index this three items with `ids`, `10`, `11` and `12`:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/item/10?pretty=true' -d '{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - Discos duros de 10TB",
  "body" : "Empiezan a sacar DD de 30GB en el mercado",
  "source_id" : "27",
  "time_order" : "1379548800:0000004153553"
}'

curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/item/11?pretty=true' -d '{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - En el 69 llegamos a la luna",
  "body" : "Se cumplen 3123 anos de la llegada a la luna y mercado",
  "source_id" : "27",
  "time_order" : "1433109600:556e006ff335c"
}'

curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/item/12?pretty=true' -d '{
  "title" : "Cadena Ser - Cumplidos 288 programas",
  "body" : "Hoy hemos cumplido los 288 programas que prometimos prometer",
  "source_id" : "69",
  "time_order" : "1390344242:0000002764401"
}'
```

I would like to know the way to search on two (as a example) specific id, let's say `10` and `11`.

I know there `ids` to search by index, but this returns the entire document with the given `id`. I would like to combine `ids` and `query_string` to make something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/item/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query": {
            "id" : {
                "type" : "item",
                "values" : ["10", "11"]
             },
            "query_string" : {
               "default_field" : "body",
               "query" : "mercado"
}}}'
```

This means I want to search for the word `mercado` of the field `body` only in the indexes `10` and `11` (but not `12`). That query of course doesn't work. Can someone tell me how can archive that goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html*) field to search on particular `ids`. Try something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "_id": [
              "10",
              "11"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "body",
            "query": "mercado"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Just a little question, without touching the code, do you know any way I can leave empty the `_id` array in order to search in all ids? I've tried things like `_id : []` or `_id : [""]` but it's not working.

Comment: glad I could help. I am not sure what exactly you want ,but if you omit `_id` clause it will search on all ids(documents) by default.

Comment: I want to mantain the code structure as sometimes I'm going to want to search on all ids, and sometimes just specific ids. That's why I just want to modify the array itself to be empty (or whatever) sometimes, so it can search in all records, or putting the specifc ids (as you stated in the answer).